# How to prevent Selenium from closing browser after each function?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm a newbie on selenium and I wrote a little python script using selenium to test some functionalities on our website.

But I notice something strange in my code. I have several functions for example :

1. Login to website
2. List item
3. Click on a link  etc.

But, each time selenium hits the bottom of a function it closes the browser and I lose my session. This forces me to put all the test in just one function.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior? I'm using selenium RC not a Webdriver.

Comment: In case you are using junit4, you can put the opening of browser in **setUp()** method having annotation **@Beforeclass** and closing of browser in **tearDown()** method having annotation **@AfterClass**. In between, you can have multiple test methods for **Login, Click on link, etc.** as **testLogin(), testClickOnLink(), etc.** under annotation **@Test**

Comment: jUnit is for Java.  The OP is using python.

Comment: Have you tried to pass the Browser instance as a parameter for each function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out :) It seems that wen you remove the test_ from the beginning of the function I can setup function wihtout the browser to be closed

Comment: How is this a relevant answer?

Comment: lol it worked XD (not really is a joke)

Answer (score 2):

That is actually by design.

In order to keep a **maintainable**, **independent** test suite, you'll need your tests to close your browser.

Picture this:

```
class MyTestClass:
  def test_method1():
    test_something()

  def test_method2():
    test_something_else()
```

Once `test_method1()` has started running, it should have it's own browser instance, and should close it afterwards.

Once `test_method2()` has started running, it should have **it's** own browser, and close it afterwards. This is a good design to have.  I'd recommend not changing it.

Comment: The fact is here I need a function for login to log into the website and another to click on links.

Comment: Your test class shouldn't have helper methods like that.. You should create a "helper class" with those types of functions, then you could do something like: `login_page.login()` in your test method

Comment: OK will do :) Thx for the tip anyway

Comment: sircapsalot is it possible to have the same session for the 2 test method you put in you comment ?